# Working with unequal sized dataframes in if-else statement in R

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes (df1,df2,df3) of unequal sizes. I want to extract certain columns depending on which dataframe is called upon. 
For example, I want to extract `column1` and `column2` if df1 is choosen, `column3` and `column4` if df2 is chosen and `column5` if df3 is choosen.
I used simple if-else statement for this purpose.

```
df <- df1

if (df==df1){
  df[,c(column1,column2)]
}else if (df==df2){
  df[,c(column3,column4)]
}else{
  df[,column5]
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> Error in Ops.data.frame(df, df1) :    ‘==’ only defined for
>   equally-sized data frames

Is there a way to solve this problem of unequal sized dataframes in R?
If not, how can I work around this problem?


Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Maybe `all.equal()` rather than `==`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested `all.equal` in a comment but it looks like it's not quite that simple.

Basically, `all.equal` will return `TRUE` if the data.frames are all equal, but it will return a character vector describing differences if not, so that doesn't quite play well with an `if` check.  What you can do is this!

```
if (all(all.equal(df, df1) == TRUE))
```

That takes the output of `all.equal` (which will either be a single `TRUE` or one or more strings) and check if it's `TRUE` that every element of all.equal is `TRUE`, which only happens when the data.frames are the same!

**Edit**

It looks like `identical` removes the need for acrobatics.  You could just do

```
if (identical(df, df1))
```