# Extract name of data.frame in R as a character without creating list of all data.frames and then calling from that list

Tags: r

I have a data frame, df. 
I assigned it to an object, x.

```
x <- df
```

I want to create an object,y ,such that y takes the characters "df" , i.e. only the name of the data frame,df in double quotes, and not the data frame itself. However I want to assign "df" to y using the created object x as input.

The output, when y is called, should be:

```
> y
[1] "df"
```

I need to extract only the name of data frame, df, and assign it to object y.

I understand that one of the ways of doing this is by creating a list of all the dataframes in the environment and then calling 'df' from that list.

I want to know if there is any other way of doing this.

Thank You.

Comment: Try using `deparse(quote(df))`

Comment: Can we ask *why* you want to do this? It seems like an XY problem - whatever your larger goal is there is probably a better way to accomplish that goal in R than trying to do this very un-R-like task.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but OP wants to only reference `x`, not `df` in creating the result :(

Comment: @Gregor You must be seeing some requirement which I missed.  +1 to your comment for using the term `un-R-like`.

Comment: @Gregor I am creating a function that uses both df and "df", i.e. the data frame as well as the name of that data frame in quotes. This is why I need to extract the name of data.frame.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen from the question, *"However I want to assign "df" to y using the created object x as input."*

Comment: Jangy, that's a good start, but why do you need a function to operate on the data and the name? Why do you need both? Just the object is enough for almost every single R function...

Comment: @Gregor please take a look at this post. The second answer has worked for me here. That is why I need a function to operate on the data and the name.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635263/working-with-unequal-sized-dataframes-in-if-else-statement-in-r/51636946#51636946

Answer (score 0):

We need two assumptions:

1. Both symbols are in same environment,
2. you have not modified either of these and thus R has not made a deep copy.

Then you can look for symbols pointing to the same address in memory.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1)
x <- df

library(pryr)
address(x)
#[1] "0x12d905c0"

adr <- vapply(ls(.GlobalEnv), function(x) {
  a <- as.symbol(x)
  setNames(eval(bquote(address(.(a))),.GlobalEnv), x)
  }, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
#          df            x 
#"0x12d905c0" "0x12d905c0"

names(adr[adr == address(x)])
[1] "df" "x"
```

However, if you pass `df` as a function parameter like `foo(x = df)` and need the name "df" inside the function, see this question: [In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function)

Comment: Thank You Sir. You are of great help... always. Much appreciated... Thanks a lot. @Roland